# jScrollPane Vertical Tabs - How can I simulate a click on a link/tab?

Tags: javascript, css, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I've implemented with success a [Vertical jScrollPane with tabs](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/invisibles.html)  
I'm trying to make a tab show up by default.

Can I do this by simulating a click on the link with the id #default ? If so, how?

The code is identical to the on that site. Here's the javascript:

```
   $(function()
{
    // Create the "tabs"
    $('.tabs').each(
        function()
        {
            var currentTab, ul = $(this);
            $(this).find('a').each(
                function(i)
                {
                    var a = $(this).bind(
                        'click',
                        function()
                        {
                            if (currentTab) {
                                ul.find('a.active').removeClass('active');
                                $(currentTab).hide();
                            }
                            currentTab = $(this).addClass('active')
                                            .attr('href');
                            $(currentTab).show().jScrollPane();
                            return false;
                        }
                    );
                    $(a.attr('href')).hide();
                }
            );
        }
    );
});
```

Here's the html code:

```
        <ul class="tabs"> 
            <li><a href="#pane1" id="default">Pane 1</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#pane2">Pane 2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#pane3">Pane 3</a></li> 
        </ul>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this not work as expected, after it's initialized?

```
$('#default').click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your reply shed the much needed light. I was trying with all kinds of code (that seemed like good code) BEFORE the menu was initialized........ and all that was needed was a line of code at the end of the script. I've added 
`$(document).ready(function(){      $('#default').click()         });`at the end of that script and voila. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!